# How to rescan a SATA hard disk devices in a RAID array remotely from the main server it is connected to?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata

I have the RAID 5 system in 4bay-hdd-case with a SATA cable connected to main server.

Cach drive is registered like these

```
/dev/sdj3
/dev/sdk3
/dev/sdl3
/dev/sdm
```

However suddenly, `/dev/sdj3` seems to have disappeared. So the RAID array is now in a “degraded” state because only three drives are seen from server.

```
/dev/sdk3
/dev/sdl3
/dev/sdm
```

Even, `fdisk -l` doesn”t show the `/dev/sdj` device.

It might be broken, so I should change the hard disk as soon as possible, but server is located remotely, so I can’t touch the hdd now.

Is there a way quick rescan the external SATA drive to check if `/dev/sdj3` is there or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can likely rescan the SCSI bus (yes, I know they are SATA disks - SATA is, I believe a subset of SCSI)  with a command like

```
 echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/hostX/scan
```

(Repeat this all for values for "hostX" visible on your system).

Note that if and when the drive does reappear it may not be /dev/sdj - it may be something else.  /var/log/syslog and/or /var/log/messages will likely have the new details.  Also, with some luck mdadm will be using UUID's rather then drive letters.  That said, you really want to work out why it dropped out the array.

Comment: Thank you very much I tried, but in vain. each hostX has the symbolic link to some file and I guess each file is linked to each drives, however there looks no disappeared disk.I want to re-scan hostX itself, maybe....